Django/Heroku - Custom 500 template
I have a template defined and loaded on S3. The template has been granted public access.
The template is referred in Heroku as variable ERROR_PAGE_URL and the S3 link is attached against this variable.
Somehow the template is not displaying and I still get the basic 500 error generated:
500 Internal Server Error
Exception inside application.

Daphne

I have (I think) applied the same approach as the custom maintenance template, which is rendered perfectly fine.
Am I reading the documentation wrong? (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-pages)
Am I using the correct variable? Or is it actually not somehting Heroku generates and I should code this in django?

Turns out I was wrong.
Considered deleting the post but then I thought, it might be useful to someone.
I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-5wFWpKQazA
in all simplicity, add the following code:
views.py
#Error Handling Templates
def custom_500(request):
    return render(request,'AppName/500.html', status=500) #AppName/ does not have to be there, this was for me.

urls.py: (In your project folder, not app)
#error handling
from django.conf.urls import handler500
handler500 = 'main.views.custom_500'

create a template called "500.html" in your templates folder
This worked for me.
(obvisouly switched debug to False in your settings)
